# Embedded YouTube on Chrome for iPad not Working

Tags: html, css, ipad, google-chrome

So I have a website called http://urbexplore.co.uk that is running really well on all devices except on the iPad version of Google Chrome.

There are 2 `iframes` embeddeded on the page that have a width `100%` of the div and `40%` of the device height.

On the iPad version of Chrome everything about the height goes out of the window and the video has a height that is about `5000%` of the device height. This is really confusing me because it works perfectly on all other devices.

Thanks in advance,
Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to fix my own problem, instead of using a`%` unit for the height I've changed to using `height: 60vh;` instead. Everything works fine in Chrome and all other browsers/devices with that change